# Reverse list of objects inside a list of object using linq

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-objects

I've a list of class type hotel which internally consists list of other class rooms. Now when i perform a descending sort i sort hotels in descending order but i also have to internally sort the rooms list on price using linq. Below is the sketch of the class structure

```
class Hotel
       - property hotelname (string)
       - property rooms  (list of rooms)

class rooms
      - property roomdesc (string)
      - property roomcharge (decimal)
```

I've applied the descending and ascending code in below way rite now.

```
lstHotels.OrderByDescending(Function(hotel) hotel.Rooms(0).roomcharge).ToList()
```

This sorts the hotel in descending as per the room charge.The 0th index room is always with least cost. Also with the descending sort i also want to sort the list of rooms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't state the question clearly. Does your code work or not? Also you talk about reversing a list in your title, but you only talk about ordering a list in your question.

Comment: Would a C# answer be welcome too? Don't know vb.net enough to express this.

Comment: Here's what the requirement is ...

I need to perform a sorting in descending order on hotels and also the rooms under those hotels.. eg below.

Hotel ABC
1st Offer with 2 rooms: 125,150
2nd Offer with 2 rooms : 175,200

Hotel XYZ
1st Offer with 2 rooms: 120,140
2nd Offer with 2 rooms : 210,220


now once i sort these offer in desc Hotel XYZ is displayed as first hotel and also i want to sort the rooms in that offer. I was able to do sort on offer but not on rooms.


@Wasp : C# answers are welcomed..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to reverse the order of rooms in a hotel, If so then you can try this.

```
Dim hotelList as List(Of Hotel) =  lstHotels.OrderByDescending(Function(hotel) hotel.Rooms(0).roomcharge).ToList()

hotelList.ForEach(AddressOf OrderRooms)


Sub OrderRooms(ByVal hotel As Hotel)
       hotel.Rooms.Reverse()
End Sub
```

Might It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what result you want, you could just need `.ThenBy`:

Firstly, here is the LINQ expression I'm using:

```
From hotel In lstHotels
    From room In hotel.Rooms
    Order By hotel.Room(0).roomcharge Descending,
             room.roomcharge Descending
```

Using LINQpad I get this:

```
lstHotels.SelectMany(Function(hotel) hotel.Rooms, _
            Function(hotel,room) New With{.hotel=hotel, .room=room}) _
     .OrderByDescending(Function(hr) hr.hotel.Rooms(0).roomcharge) _
     .ThenByDescending(Function(hr) hr.room.roomcharge)
```

(but this is untested -- it is based upon the `AsQueryable` output from a slightly different dataset already coded for another SO answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have these classes:

```
public class Hotel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; } // List<Room> to keep it simple, 
                                          // you could/should expose it 
                                          // in a better way
}

public class Room
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Charge { get; set; }
}
```

I think the right approach would not be to sort the `Rooms` member, but to do a Linq query that projects the desired sort in new data structures through anonymous types:

```
var report = from o in offers
             orderby o.Name descending
             select new 
             { 
                o.Name, 
                Rooms = from r in o.Rooms
                        orderby r.Charge
                        select r 
             };
```

This way you have an enumeration of anonymous types where the first member is the name of the hotel, and the second an enumeration of rooms sorted the way you want. You might want to expose the whole hotel instance replacing `o.Name` with `Hotel = o` in your projection, as you like it.